# Why redeclaring variables in body is forbidden but inside a for loop isn't, with c++?

Tags: c++

If I have this following code(very simple example):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 20;
    cout << a << endl;
    int a = 15;
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

After running it, it gives the following error: **redeclaration of variable a**. Which I understand perfectly the reason behind it.

But the following code(the same side effect as the one above, but different):

```
int main()
{
    int T[2];
    T[0] = 20;
    T[1] = 15;
    for(int g=0; g<2; g++)
    {
        int a = T[g];
        cout << a << endl;
    }
}
```

The variable a is redeclared without any fluff and it works. For me is confusing, why this happens? Or the reason behind this, is that the variable are redeclared in different scopes because of the for loop, or there is another correct reason behind it?

Comment: There is no variable being redeclared in the second version. There is just one declaration, it doesn't matter how many times the control flow passes over the source line where it appears.

Comment: scope blocks! everything declared as local between the {} is not visible externally.  In the loop... each iteration of the loop has its own "copy" of that scope block... meaning the local for one loop is not visible in the next.

Comment: so everything that is declared in any {}, has its own mini-universes if variables are declared they exist only there, but in the whole universe(kind of ~ body) nothing is known about them?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Comment: anything defined as a local is disposed of at the end of a scope block.  You can see this if you create a local class instance... MyClass c() in the scope block.  At the end of the scope block the deconstructor is called.

Comment: now it's fine, my first assumption, initially, was based on that only functions and procedures are creating different scopes, but now everything is clear with {}.

Comment: To give you some more concepts that you might lack if you had problems here: 1. Try to think about what needs to be in the memory and which part of the program. In programs with big data structures, you will want to control that, in order to have memory left. 2. If you haven't thought about where regular variables lived, you might not be aware about where which allocated memory lives. You might want to read into pointers and how they can cause memory leaks, since that might be a following mistake.

Comment: @Aziuth thanks for insight, I just started learning C++ 3 months ago, and it's my first kind of low level language that I want to learn, and the mistakes are punished even more heavier than I was used with learning javascript or php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One word: [**scope**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).

A `{}` pair creates a new scope. Scopes can be nested.

In the first example, there are two separate `a` variables being declared in the same scope, which is not allowed.

In the second example, there is only one `a` variable being declared, not two variables (so no conflict to begin with) in the scope of the `for` loop's body.  Just because a loop runs multiple times does not mean multiple variables are declared.  Since `a` is local to the loop body, every iteration of the loop allocates, uses, and frees the `a` variable each time (in reality, the compiler optimizes to reuse the same memory each time).

Answer (score 2):

C++ variables have block scope. If blocks are nested, as with a for loop, the variable with the most inner nesting is the one referred to. This allows cutting ad pasting of blocks without renaming their local variables.

Answer (score 2):

An excellent way to get concept of it:
Run following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a = 20;
    cout << &a << endl;
    int a = 15;
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
     int T[2];
     T[0] = 20;
     T[1] = 15;
     for(int g=0; g<2; g++)
     {
         int a = T[g];
         cout << &a << endl;
     }
}
```

As you know, reference operator (&) returns variable address in memory. Now if address of two variables differ, you can conclude that they are not the same.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider three issues:

- first in c++ variables are block-scope.in your case it means you could define same variable in every {};
- each loop in for-loop is a context and in your case just imagine you have n block of {}
- you cant define same variable (even in different type) in a block..in your case int a=20 and int a=15 are on the same block and this throws exeption.. you just need to define a variable once and change the value like this: int a=20; a=15;

Answer (score 1):

the reason is simple in your case this concept called local variable lifetime:

in your `main` first example you declare `a` tow times at the same scope so it will give you declaration error.

in second example you declare `a = T[g]` inside scope of for loop so it will not give you error because outside for loop scope the variable lifetime end also you can consider it doesn't exist.

to understand this concept will see this example and try it:

```
 int a = 4;
 for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
        int a = 2;
        cout << a << endl;
  }
       cout << a << endl;
```

in this example it will print in side scope of for loop:

```
2
2
2
2
```

and print outside for loop scope:

```
4
```

this concept called local variable scope lifetime.

Answer (score -3):

It doesn't even matter; because compilers are smart enough these days to read the declaration.  The only thing that matters is that the space that you have saved in the above example.  You have just made the compiler confused by allowing same identifiers for two different values.  One thing that matters is speed of execution but it is just negligible in these cases.

Comment: Wrong. The "a" from iteration 1 does not exist when iteration 2 starts. Also, try to write in proper english. If you make a spelling mistake, sure, happens, but don't use "u" instead of "you" and use some commas and dots. Your sentences are tiresome to read.